# UINavigationBar title is flying out of bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

When I push a view controller to my navigation controller that is half the screen, for some reason the previous view controller title flies out of bounds. This only happened in iOS 5 and not iOS 6. Any idea why this might be happening or how we could solve it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set navigation bar Title like this way :-

[image]

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
       [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

       UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)] autorelease];
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

       UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
       [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       [label setNumberOfLines:0];
       [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
       [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
       [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
       NSString    *str =@"1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123456";
       [label setText:str];
       self.navigationItem.titleView = label;

 }
```